# How can I install Shopify Custom App using laravel backend

Tags: shopify-api

I am creating a custom app and install using the development store, but unable to install it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoCns.png)

However I have set up the App Url and Distribution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDCxz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80WDy.png)